# How to make a `Tool` window always on top of 2 or more Main window?

Tags: c++, qt, focus, z-order

**Fast question**

In a QT C++ project, there are 2 main windows (focus can be set indiferently to any of them), and a `tool` window which shall be on top of the 2 main windows.

How to implement such feature?

**Detailed question:**

For one main window and one tool window, is quite easy to solve:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

int main( int n, char* args[])
{
    QApplication app(n, args);
    QWidget mainWindow;
    QWidget subWindow(&mainWindow);
    subWindow.setWindowFlags(subWindow.windowFlags() | Qt::Tool);
    mainWindow.show();
    subWindow.show();


    return app.exec();
}
```

- The main window is always below the tool window.
- The interaction with the main window is possible
- minimizing/closing the main window will affect the tool window
- Another application could cover the main window or both windows (**they are not top-most**)

I would like the same feature, but having 2 main window. Imagine a Video player in which the tool window provide "play/stop" control over both images:

- Each main window has the same focus weight: focus could be given to any of them, which would cover the other, but never the tool window.
- The tool is always on top of the two others.

Comment: This may help: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#raise - You can `raise()` the tool window above the others. Also, see the "Note" on that function

Comment: Yes, that seem the point. Even if a bit ugly. If you write an answer with it, I will accept/vote it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `raise()` the tool window above the others.

This may help: [void QWidget::raise() documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#raise)

Also, see the "Note" on that function.

Answer (score -2):

Add Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint to the flags

Comment: That is a pretty bad idea: any other windows could not cover my application. On the other hand, making my application top-most with the process-manager would break this rule.